# HTML Validation & Checking

Tags: html, validation

This may be a bit of a random question but I don't know who else to ask because I can't find any answers to this ...

I have a website - https://www.romaheritage.co.uk - and I'm working on cleaning up the code and improving the experience a bit.

Now I've run it through the W3C validation website (https://validator.w3.org/) and there is no errors and I'm also using Nibbler (http://nibbler.silktide.com/en) to test the various aspects of it but it's throwing up a few odd problems;

Firstly, it keeps throwing up the error;

"The doctype of this website couldn't be determined."

even though I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

as the first line of the html page(s).
Testing other websites this error doesn't appear, so what am I doing wrong?

Secondly, Nibbler doesn't seem to be able to validate the website with W3C, even though it gives you the direct link to test with W3C and it checks out fine! Other websites I've tested with Nibbler can validate with W3C so again, am I doing something wrong?

Any help or advice anyone could give would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I copied your page index from Chrome inspection mode (sorry :-( ) to W3 Validator and it seems it didn't copied the first line, which contains your error with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then I just added it to the first line in "Validate in direct input" option in W3 Validator and it gave me no errors.

So I would recommend you not to worry about it, or check it one more time, if you pasted your code with  tag in the first line.

Comment: Weird ... I wasn't having issues with W3C Validator , if I entered the URL it validates fine. The issue was with Nibbler; I wonder if it copies the code somehow and doesn't see the first line in a similar way to what you describe above ...

Comment: Well, according my opinion it's fine when you got no errors with W3C validator. Though it is W3C.